# Chrome extension: dealing with multiple message listeners

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

My extension has `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` defined in both the background page and a content script.  Some messages need to be caught by the background page, others by the content script.  My problem is that for some reason one of my content scripts does not catch messages.

My background page contains:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
    if (msg["injectCss"]) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ beginInject: msg.injectCss.files.length });
        injectCss(sender.tab.id, msg.injectCss.files, 0, function () {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ endInject: true });
            respond();
        });
    }
});
```

My content script contains:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
    if (msg["beginInject"]) {
        //do something
        respond();
    }
});
```

When `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ beginInject: msg.injectCss.files.length });` gets called from the background page, the background page itself catches the message rather than the content script.

**Question:  Is there a way to mark a message as "not handled yet" so that other listeners can have a chance to catch it and handle it?**

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the answer was fairly simple:

In order to send a message specifically to a content script, use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message, callback)`.  To send a message anywhere else, use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, callback)`.